# Updating project from tags in subversion?

Tags: svn

I'm somewhat new to using tags in subversion but I think I got the hang out of. When I'm ready to release a new build, I tag it with the build number. So on the server, I checkout that tag and it downloads all the files. Well then the next week, I release a new build but I can't checkout to the new tag since it's already checked out to the other tag. So my question is, do I just have to wipe out everything and then check it out with the new tag? Or is there someway to get it to do some sort of update to the new tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is:

1. Tag the new build with a new build number
2. In the server, checkout from that tag

Think of a tag as a snapshot of your source code at a particular time rather than a thing that changes (updates) as you develop (though you can commit to a tag and treat it like a branch, but I digress).

Comment: I get that but what do you do when you want to upgrade to a new tag? Just wipe out the whole project and check it out again?

Comment: That's what I would do. Delete the old directory and do a fresh checkout of the new tag.

Answer (score 0):

The tags are just markers for you. You only check out tags for building your software however you don't modify them. If you need to make changes to a older version you create a branch. Otherwise you just continue development in your trunk and create new tags for your releases.

Comment: I think maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I am not modifying them. So if I check out tag 1.0.0 to a directory, then I create a new tag in svn, 1.0.1. Now I want to checkout this tag to that same directory. How do I do that?

Comment: I'd delete the old directory and do a fresh clean checkout from the new tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that tags are the right tool for the job (I don't know the exact details so I can't decide for you). You use a tag to take a "snapshot" of a given revision and you normally do an **export** to wherever you want to use it, rather than a **checkout**. Tags are not supposed to change so there's not benefit in linking a working copy to a tag. On the contrary, if you create a branch called, e.g, "production", you can just *update* your live server's working copy when you are ready to deploy changes.

With your current procedure, you'd need to do a **switch** in your live server's working copy so it points to the new tag. Now I think about it, I admit it has a benefit: you only need to transmit changed files.